# Overriding Equals for an object with ID

Tags: .net, vb.net, equals

Is it the best override for `Equals` (in VB.NET) for an object having an unique `ID`?

```
  Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
    If obj Is Nothing OrElse Not [GetType]().Equals(obj.GetType()) Then
      Return False
    End If
    Dim otherMyObject As MyObject = DirectCast(obj, MyObject)
    Return Me.Id = otherMyObject.Id
  End Function
```

I took that example from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx), but not entirely sure if from all points of view (including performance) is the better solution.

EDIT:

How about comparing with this version:

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
  Dim otherMyObject As MyObject = TryCast(obj, MyObject)
  If otherMyObject Is Nothing Then
    Return False
  Else
    Return Me.Id = otherMyObject.Id
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "an unique ID". If you can guarantee that there won't be any other objects in memory with the same ID, you can just inherit the functionality from `Object`. If, however, you want to treat two objects of the same type and ID as being equal, then this looks fine. You'd want to override `GetHashCode` as well though.

You really need to consider what is going to *use* the equality implementation and what they're expecting. If there can be two distinct objects with the same ID but different other properties, what does it mean for those to be "equal"? Is that appropriate or not?

It *may* make more sense to implement `IEqualityComparer(Of T)` in something like an "`IdEqualityComparer`" type, for example. That's a good way of expressing that an equality relation is *useful* but not necessarily a "natural, comprehensive" equality relation.

Comment: @serhio: Indeed, as per your code. Inheritance and equality are painful together. I would normally prefer *not* to override Equals for non-sealed types.

Comment: How about the second variant (in the edit)? Is it less performant?

Comment: @serhio: That doesn't do the same thing. That will let a banana with ID=1 equal an apple with ID=1, assuming this is declared in Fruit.

Comment: Ok, I understand for the inheritance. But from the point of view of performance, do you think first varaint is better?

Comment: @serhio: I doubt it makes any significant difference from a performance point of view. The *correctness* aspect is hugely important though - let that guide you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements for "Equals" in your application.  Does an instance `ClassA` with the same `Id` property **always** "Equal" another instance with the same `Id`?  What if instance #1 has been changed, and some of the properties are different than instance #2, but still have the same `Id`.  Are they still equal?  In most definitions this would not be equal, but that's entirely up to your own requirements.

Comment: yes, ID_1 = ID_2 => _1 === _2, other properties does not matter.